# Why `search.web` YQL table doesn't work anymore?

Tags: yql, yahoo-pipes, yahoo-api

When I'm using `search.web` YQL table, I always get the error:

> No definition found for Table search.web

in my YQL statements. Even when using `SELECT url FROM search.web(0,10) WHERE query="stackoverflow"` for example.

So I am assuming Yahoo discontinued `search.web` or BOSS? What are the alternatives? Is there still a similar way to crawl the web?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can read in YQL Blog:

> We’ve removed all search tables that relied on the BOSS v1 API (search.web, search.image, and search.news) as the aforementioned BOSS v1 no longer exists as of today (http://www.ysearchblog.com/2011/06/30/you-asked-for-this-boss-v2-updates/).
>
> For those of you relying on those tables please consider using the community BOSS v2 table (https://github.com/yql/yql-tables/blob/master/boss/boss.search.xml).
>
> Thanks -YQL Team

Source: [Search tables and BOSS v1 in YQL Blog](http://web.archive.org/web/20140408085951/http://www.yqlblog.net/blog/2011/07/20/search-tables-and-boss-v1/).

---

As a result, you should move to another search service like Y! BOSS v2. As mentioned above there are already open data tables for that, and an example query would look like:

```
SELECT * FROM boss.search WHERE query="stackoverflow"
AND ck="your oauth consumer key" 
AND secret="your oauth secret"
```

Another alternative is to use Bing search:

```
SELECT * FROM microsoft.bing.web WHERE query="stackoverflow"
```

Answer (score 1):

BOSS v1 API has been depreciated (as in [YQL Blog](http://web.archive.org/web/20140408085951/http://www.yqlblog.net/blog/2011/07/20/search-tables-and-boss-v1/)), so you should use BOSS v2 API which works exactly the same, but the table is called `boss.search` and it's available in [Yahoo YQL Dev Console](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/) (just activate *Show Community Tables* or check at [GitHub](https://github.com/yql/yql-tables/tree/master/boss)).

To use BOSS v2 API, you need to have your own *Consumer Key* and *Consumer Secret* which can be generated at [Yahoo Dev Apps](https://developer.apps.yahoo.com/projects) by creating a new app.

Sample usage:

```
select * from boss.search where q = "sam pullara" AND (ck = 'ConsumerKey') AND (secret = 'SECRET');
```