# Is yql Bing search or BOSS search v2 still valid?

Tags: yql

I'm trying to do large amount of search queries automatically, and YQL has very attractive limitation settings. However, when I was following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6917007/why-search-web-yql-table-doesnt-work-anymore), hoping I could use YQL Bing Search or BOSS v2, through both YQL Console and url, both told me no defination of the tables...

But I found yql-tables [here](https://github.com/yql/yql-tables), which includes Bing search and BOSS search and many other tables that cannot be found through YQl Console `Show Tables`

The tutorials about YQL I have found are all majorly happened in 2011, that's many years ago...

So, I'm wondering, whether [tables here](https://github.com/yql/yql-tables) are still valid? If so, do you know how can I use **microsoft.bing.web** or **boss.search** to get the query results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... that cannot be found through YQl Console `Show Tables`

Be sure to enable "Show Community Tables" (on the left of the page, above the tables list) as shown below.

[image: Show Community Tables Checkbox]